# I am getting this error when trying to test an input against a table

Tags: python

When I run this code I get this error

```
line 101, in seventh_question
    if int(weight) >= heightandweight[height][2]:
KeyError: 187
```

**Code:**

```
def seventh_question():

       height = int(input("\nWhat is your height in centimeters? "))

       if height < 147:
             height = 147
    
       if height >= 193:
             height = 193

       weight = int(input("\nWhat is your weight in Kg's? "))

       if int(weight) >= heightandweight[height][2]:
             return 3

       if int(weight) >= heightandweight[height][1]:
             return 2

       if int(weight) >= heightandweight[height][0]:
             return 1

       with open("height_weight.json") as f:
       heightandweight = json.load(f)
       f.close()
```

Comment: Do you have a 187 key in `heightandweight` dictionary?

Comment: fix the indentation first ? is that intentional opening json inside the function

Comment: may be 187 in string format in `heightandweight` dict did you check?

Comment: There is no `187` in `heightandweight`

Comment: Thank you for all who responded. I was able to get it working. IDK what was going wrong but it is fixed now.

Comment: To answer your questions. Yes, I did have a 187 key in the dictionary. IDK why the indentation is so messed up but no opening the JSON file was not supposed to be there.